# When I scroll past the end of my id #home I want #about to load not before

Tags: jquery

Hi am am trying to do something using jquery.. now what I want is when I scroll past my #home div which is in a section I want it to fire and allow me to call

```
$('#about').show(1300);
```

I don't want the about section to show anytime before we scroll past the #home section.

I have tried this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var anchor_offset = $('a[href="#home"]').offset().top;    
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
         if ( $(window).scrollTop() > anchor_offset ) 
             $('#about').show(1300);
    });
});
```

But it doesn't fire on time at all.

Here my html.

```
<section id="home">
     <article>
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Dom</h2>
        </div>
      </article>
</section>

<section id="about">
   <article>
      <div class="row">
         <p>test about</p>
      </div>

    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: question is unclear, as you're using #home in your code but saying about #about....

Comment: sorry changed it to #about my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your selector. You're selecting an `<a>` element that doesn't exist.

```
//var anchor_offset = $('a[href="#home"]').offset().top;
var anchor_offset = $('#home').offset().top; //Use this instead
```